# Could not able get youtube URL in android webview while i navigate to another video. onPageStarted method is not called. Other urls called correctly

Tags: android

onPageStarted method is called only While i load url firsttime.After that whenever i click a video,it is opening but onPageStarted method is not called. Other webpage urls are working correctly.

I am getting url from onPageStarted callback and refresh functionality for user with swipeRefreshLayout. When pull from top its load again to home page only.

Here is the code :

```
     webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                    mCurrentUrl = url;     

               }
      }
```

And the swipe refresh :

```
 binding.newsSwipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new 
                 SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                loadWebView();
       }
  });
```

Loadwebview code:

```
 private void loadWebView(){
        try {         
              webView.loadUrl(mCurrentUrl);
         
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: code added in question

Answer (score 0):

This is because Youtube does not load a new page every time you click a video. It uses AJAX, which only updates the page's content without the need for postback.

However, you can override `onReceivedTitle()` callback function of `WebChromeClient` class. It will be triggered every time there is a new page title received, or when you navigate to a new video.

Hope it helps